# Running EXE installer through InstallShield

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I'm currently using InstallShield to silently install an application, however I am stuck at a pretty primitive stage.

All of the files unpack to all of the locations I want them to, and everything goes according to plan except the installation of the .EXE within my project.

I want to move the .EXE installer that is contained within my project into the installation folder (which happens successfully), and then run it silently so that it installs.

I have messed with many different settings in the custom action area, where I run a .EXE passing in the silent parameters as command line arguments, but the program simply does not install and the entire installation of my project completes successfully. No matter where I seem to add it to the sequence, or if I check the exit code.

When I added this custom action to install, however, the installation takes much longer almost as if it is actually running this exe file. But in the end, the program is nowhere to be found on the target machine.

Any suggestions? I've read multiple documents on installing an exe through custom action that is installed with the project, but no luck.

I really have no idea what's going on.

Comment: It isn't clear; you are installing a file that you want to run silently that installs your software?

Comment: Installing software that is required by my software to function properly. I waned to install it silently during the installation of my own software.... However I figured it out, InstallShield was just being really nit picky about where it is executed in the sequence.

Comment: It's very unclear, but perhaps you are trying to install MSI from MSI. Your EXEs can contain MSIs inside. But anyway use logging and read log files, I think you will find there more useful information.